# Ubuntu One music store - in my currency?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I'm really curious about the Ubuntu One music store, but I noticed all the prices are in €, and my country doesn't use Euro. Can or will the UOMS translate the prices into sek for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support for changing the display currency in the store.  Since the purchases are via credit card, there shouldn't be any problems making purchases with the current exchange rate being used for the transaction.